# Hiding legend item box when using check box in Highcharts

Tags: checkbox, highcharts, legend

The following is my chart:

http://jsfiddle.net/eR4vn/1/

My requirement is to hide the legend item symbol alone (not the label) and use the checkbox as a means to select and deselect series . I have managed to achieve this.

However,while deselecting the series,the gray box appears beside the legend label.Using itemHiddenStyle property of legend applies the color to the legend text also thus hiding it.

http://jsfiddle.net/eR4vn/2/

Is there anyway to achieve this requirement?

Comment: What exactly is wrong with this demo: http://jsfiddle.net/eR4vn/3/ ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think you want to remove only legend symbol,

i suggest you to go with

```
legend:{
symbolWidth: 0
}
```

then this http://jsfiddle.net/eR4vn/4/ might help you